# grouping is not recognized by dplyr::mutate( cur_group_id)

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, grouping

Here is my dataset

```
  record_id voucher_number ice   sets      
       <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>
 1         1 app1           app   app                     
 2         1 00000          1     1    
 3         1 11111          1     2    
 4         1 22222          1     3    
 5         1 11111          2     4    
 6         2 app2           app   app  
 7         2 33333          1     1    
 8         2 44444          1     2    
 9         2 33333          2     3    
10         2 33333          3     4    
11         3 app3           app   app  
12         3 55555          1     1    
13         3 66666          1     2    
14         3 55555          2     3    
15         3 66666          2     4    
16         3 55555          3     5    
17         3 77777          1     6
```

I am trying to create another variable column to represent different combinations of `record_id` and `voucher_number` in set. When I use the following snippet of code

```
dplyr::group_by(
       record_id,
       voucher_number
       ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
       voucher_sets = cur_group_id()
    )
```

Now `cur_group_id` is working fine but its not recognizing grouping at the record_id level and the result appears as follows:

```
  record_id voucher_number ice   voucher_sets   expectation_first  expect_last
       <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>
 1         1 app1           app   1                                  application
 2         1 00000          1     2                    1                 1
 3         1 11111          1     3                    2                 2   
 4         1 22222          1     4                    3                 3   
 5         1 11111          2     3                    2                 2  
 6         2 app2           app   5                                  application
 7         2 33333          1     6                    1                 1
 8         2 44444          1     7                    2                 2   
 9         2 33333          2     6                    1                 1    
10         2 33333          3     6                    1                 1   
11         3 app3           app   8                                   application
12         3 55555          1     9                    1                 1
13         3 66666          1     10                   2                 2
14         3 55555          2     9                    1                 1  
15         3 66666          2     10                   2                 2   
16         3 55555          3     5                    1                 1   
17         3 77777          1     6                    3                 3
```

How do I approach this and what's going on wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please see ```expectation_first ``` and  ```expect_last``` column above. Those should be my intended outcome.

Comment: Where would "application" come from though? There's nothing in your data that signals that—seems like some sort of rule you need to write. And I'm not sure what you mean by first & last; the group IDs come from unique combinations of all grouping variables, so (record_id = 1, voucher = 000) would have one group ID, and (record_id = 2, voucher = 000) would have another ID

Comment: @ camille, sorry should have mentioned applicated is the reformatted value for ```app``` under column ```ice```. Absolutely that's what I want however i want index values within each record id since for each record id, I have many voucher_numbers. Thanks

Comment: maybe you can use a conditional and lag() to see the row above and reset numeration in case it founds "app"

Comment: That's fine @ Alvaro Morales, but the indexing problem still stays as shown in ```expectation_first``` column.

Comment: You should not use `cur_group_id()` here. Try with `row_number()`.

Comment: Figured out how to do it the simple way. Thanks everyone! :)